# how to get numer of sections in each places with laravel eloquent, sql query or any method

Tags: php, laravel

I had two tables places and sections
when add new section it save place id in database

i need to show number of sections "count sections" for each place with [any method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAyrM.png)

this Schema for sections table

```
Schema::create('sections', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('sections_name', 255);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('places_id');
            $table->foreign('places_id')->references('id')->on('places')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

this Schema for places table

```
Schema::create('places', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('users_id');
            $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('places_name', 255);
            $table->timestamps();
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a [Relationship between your models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), like this:

```php
class Place extends Model
{
    public function sections()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Section::class);
    }
}
```

You can use the [withCount method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) of Eloquent.

```php
use App\Models\Place;
 
$places = Place::withCount('sections')->get();
 
foreach ($places as $place) {
    echo $place->sections_count;
}
```

The `$place->sections_count` can be referenced in the web using that same name.